# Moving calls between conferences UCMA4

Tags: c#, lync, ucma

I want to take a call in one conference, and move it into another conference, and STILL remain the SIP control of that call.
I tried with Eject the user from the first conference, and then to join another conference, but when I do eject the user, the call gets terminated and lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to get the call as a `BackToBackCall` (`B2B`) instead of a normal call. The `B2B` call means you UCMA application is acting like a man-in-the-middle for a call: One side (called a "leg") will go to the original call, the other leg will go to your conference, but all the control messages flow through your application.

Since you are in control of the whole call, you can then replace one leg of the `B2B` call with another, allowing you to move your calls between conferences.

Some resources:

- [Using UCMA 3.0 BackToBackCall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228141%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [Moving calls between conferences in UCMA 3.0](https://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2010/12/moving-calls-between-conferences-in-ucma-3-0/)

Comment: The second resource link seemed promissing, but, as it says, "keep in mind that this process is not repeatable. When you transfer the call using AudioVideoMcuSession.BeginTransfer, you are pulling it out of the back-to-back arrangement". The call I have control of is already a B2B call, but how do you replace a call leg? As far as I can see, the call legs are read-only.

Comment: Your best bet would be to look into something called "**self-transfer**": Instead of transferring to the next conference, transfer back to your own application. This gives you a new incoming call with which you can build a new B2B call to another conference.

Comment: I'm now fiddling with a self-transfer to move it from one conference to another. Its going from ConfB.OnIncomingCall (with an application context), calling the sipuri of ConfA, but ConfA.OnIncomingCall determines it as a new call, which means I generate a new call ID for it, which I don't want... Can I somehow place an object as ApplicationContext on a B2BUA?? If I can get my app to recognize existing calls on incoming of the second conference, then I think I have the solution.

Comment: For this I add an extra SIP header to the self-transfer with a correlation ID. The incoming call handler on the endpoint checks for this header: If it is there, find the related existing handler, otherwise create a new one.

Comment: So you are actually doing an "application context" by your own? But that requires a list with all calls in any queue, that you can do a call lookup on to see if the call exist in any other queue, doesn't it? Btw, how do you add this additional SIP header to a B2B-call?